# Angular i18n Property 'currentLang' does not exist on type string

Tags: angular

i am beginner in angular , i wanted to use i18n to create a multilangual angular 12 app so i followed a tutorial on https://www.remotestack.io/build-angular-multilingual-i18n-app-with-ngx-translate/
and i did everything that was mentionned but i got an error that says:

Property 'currentLang' does not exist on type 'string'
33           [selected]="localization === localization.currentLang">
~~~~~~~~~~~

```
      src/app/template/ui/structure/navbar/navbar.component.ts:7:16
        7   templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component NavbarComponent.


here my navbar view:

<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
    <img src="assets/images/logo.png" width="50" height="50" alt="Info Logo" />
    Info School
  </a>
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
        <li  [ngClass]="{'active': currentRoute === '/'}" class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/">{{'navbar-home' | translate }}</a>
        </li>
        <li  [ngClass]="{'active': currentRoute === '/login'}" class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login">{{'navbar-login' | translate}}</a>
        </li>
        <li [ngClass]="{'active': currentRoute === '/courses'}" class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/courses">{{'navbar-courses' | translate}}</a>
        </li>
        <li [ngClass]="{'active': currentRoute === '/animations'}" class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/animations">{{'navbar-animations' | translate}}</a>
        </li> 
    </ul>
    
    <span class="form-inline">
      <select class="form-control" #langauge (change)="translateSite(langauge.value)">
        
        <option *ngFor="let localization of translateService.getLangs()" [value]="localization"
          [selected]="localization === localization.currentLang">
          {{ localization }}
        </option>

      </select>
    </span>
    
    <ul class="nav-item navbar-nav  navbar-right">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown language-dropdown d-none d-sm-flex align-items-center ">
        <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center dropdown-toggle" id="LanguageDropdown" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          <div class="d-inline-flex mr-3">
            <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></i>
          </div>
          <span class="profile-text font-weight-normal">English</span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left navbar-dropdown my-2 my-lg-0 py-2" aria-labelledby="LanguageDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></i> English </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-fr"></i> French </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-ae"></i> Arabic </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-ru"></i> Russian </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
 
    
    <form action="aaa.php" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 rounded-pill" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0 rounded-pill " type="submit">{{'search' | translate}}</button>
    </form>

  </div>
</nav>

</header>
```

here my navbar ts file:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
})

export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

   @Input() currentRoute: string;

  constructor(private router: Router,public translateService: TranslateService) { 
    translateService.addLangs(['en','uk','fr','ru','ar','es']);
    translateService.setDefaultLang('en');
    console.log(this.router.url);
    this.currentRoute = this.router.url;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  translateSite(langauge: string) {
    this.translateService.use(langauge);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option *ngFor="let localization of translateService.getLangs()"
    [value]="localization"
    [selected]="localization === localization.currentLang">
      {{ localization }}
</option
```

1.) getLangs() returns an array of strings

2.) *ngFor iterates this array, storing the current string value in `localization`

3.) `[selected]="localization === localization.currentLang"` tries to access the property `currentLang` of a string - which a string does not have.

Besides that, the expression in 3.) is likely to be false in almost all scenarios (short of cyclic objects). On the left-hand side you expect `localization` to be a string and on the right-hand side you use it like an object with a `currentLang` property and you compare both for equality.

Comment: so what i should do to solve the problem?

Comment: This is not meant to be discouraging or hostile in any way: Either you find someone to write up a working solution of whatever you tried to achieve (won't be me), or you will have to read the ngx-translate docs and start fixing bugs one by one. It is very hard for third parties to provide a piece of code to you which will seamlessly integrate into your project. Sad, but true.

Comment: i am trying my best

Answer (score 0):

Just replace it with :

```
translateService.currentLang
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).